# How to fix 'Gatt write characteristic FAILED.' exception in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to do a **GATT write operation** in a BLE after **Notification** where I am getting the value from server. The **write operation works fine when there is no prior GATT operation** like **Notification**. So this is the code where I am **reading the value through notification**

```
public async Task ReadConfigData(ICharacteristic characteristics)
        {
            if (characteristics != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(_device);
                   
                        characteristics.ValueUpdated += (o, e) =>
                    {
                          Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                         {
                        //var readvalue2 = characteristics.Value;
                        var bytes = e.Characteristic.Value;
                        //var readvalue = await characteristics.ReadAsync();
                        BLEresultnew = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                        Console.WriteLine(BLEresultnew);
                        //if(BLEresultnew.Contains("start"))
                        //{
                        concat += BLEresultnew;
                             //}
                         });
                    };
                    await characteristics.StartUpdatesAsync();
                   
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
```

This is how I am doing the **write operation**

```
 public async task WriteDataAsync(String data)
        {
            if (_characteristicsBLE != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    
                       // await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(_device);
                        byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    int start = 0;
                    while (start < senddata.Length)
                    {
                        
                            int chunkLength = Math.Min(20, senddata.Length - start);
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkLength];
                        Array.Copy(senddata, start, chunk, 0, chunkLength);
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(300);
                            await _characteristicsBLE.WriteAsync(chunk);
                        });
                        start += 20;
                        
                    }

                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
```

I have even called the **write operation in main thread** to avoid any **threading issue**. But still I get **GATT error**. I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to run IO operation on MAIN thread. That is not possible and Android won't let you do this. This rises more issues than starting new thread and handling other possible "threading issues". I recommend you starting new thread and on finishing it's job, you can call some function and dispatch to MAIN thread. Or you should be able to use async&await in C#.